# directory structure to access .sh file from war

Tags: java

I have a .sh file i am creating a war file wheter in the classes are under web-inf/classes/test/test.class .i am accessing .sh file from test class using the following syntax
string cmd="./test.sh"
runtime api

i am not able to access this file if i place it under web-inf/classes .i want to know where can i place .s file in war to access the path from test.class as ./test.sh ?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but, really, you should: 1. Take some time to format your questions, use proper capitalization and punctuation 2. Don't post X time the same question (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893099/not-able-to-run-sh-file-using-java) 3. Learn how to ask "smart questions" 4. Read the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment in the other question, you are using the following code to call your script:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

As explained in the javadoc, this is equivalent to the invocation of [`exec`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File))`(command, null, null)` which *behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation [`exec`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File))`(cmdarray, envp, dir)`*. Now, if we look at the javadoc of [`exec`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File))`(String[] cmdarray, String[] envp, File dir)`, we can read:

> The working directory of the new subprocess is specified by `dir`. If `dir` is `null`, the subprocess inherits the current working directory of the current process.

In other words, in your case, your script `test.sh` is expected to be located in the *working directory* of your application server, i.e. the location in the file system from where the `java` command was invoked (which is certainly not `WEB-INF/classes`). This directory is set in the `user.dir` system property that you can read as follow:

```
String cwd = System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

Also note that you **can't** [change the working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java). Actually, you should theoretically write your code so it does not depend on the current working directory for portability (even if this doesn't really matter in your case as using the `Runtime` API makes your code not really portable anyway).

To summarize, you have several options (none of them is really portable as I said but the last one is "less worse"):

- Put the `hello.sh` script in the working directory of the app server.
- Put it somewhere else and point on it relatively to the working directory (`./path/to/hello.sh`).
- Put it somewhere else and point on it with an absolute path (`/path/to/hello.sh`).
- Put it somewhere else and use the `dir` parameter when invoking `exec()`.
- Put it in the WAR and read it using `getResourceAsStream()`, write it in the tmp dir, make it executable and `exec()` it **as suggested by Brian**.

In my opinion, the last option is the (only) way to go and can be implemented like this (assuming the script is in the same package as your class i.e. `WEB-INF/classes/test/hello.sh`):

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("hello.sh");

String[] cmd = null;
File tempFile = null;

tempFile = File.createTempFile("hello", "sh");
// extract the embedded hello.sh file from the war and save it to above file
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytes;
while( (bytes = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    os.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
}
os.close();      

tempFile.setExecutable(true);

cmd = new String[] { tempFile.getAbsolutePath() };

Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec(cmd);
```

Comment: how to make sh file executable in java code?
tempFile.setExecutable(true); does not work

Comment: That's strange and I don't know any other way. What are the permissions of the file?

Answer (score 0):

I would read the `.sh` via [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html).

You then have two choices:

1. Write it to a directory (perhaps `/tmp` ?), change the permissions and then execute it from there.
2. (a little more involved). Execute a `/bin/bash` via [Runtime.exec()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) and then pipe the script in via stdin.

You won't be able to execute the script *directly* from the .war structure.